# Python - Count Numbers of Different Digits in String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to Python, please help.

**I can only use if else statements, no loops or anything special like that.**

This program asks the user for one string.
It counts the number of different digits in the string.  for
example a11111a1a1 contains a single digit, while a1s2d1d2d1d2d1
contains 2 digits.

Examples:

```
% python3 countNumbers.py
enter string: qwerty
there are no digits in string: "qwerty"

% python3 countNumbers.py
enter string: asdf1sdfg
there is one digit in string: "asdf1sdfg"

% python3 countNumbers.py
enter string: as1as2as333333
there are 3 different digits in string: "as1as2as333333"

% python3 countNumbers.py
enter string: a0123456789x
there are 10 different digits in string: "a0123456789x"
```

```
num = input("enter string: ")
count = 0

if "0" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "1" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "2" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "3" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "4" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "5" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "6" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "7" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "8" in num:
    count = count + 1
if "9" in num:
    count = count + 1

if count >= 1:
    print("there is one digit in string: ", num)
elif count >= 2:
    print("there are two digits in string: ", num)
else:
    print("there are no digits in string: ", num)
```

Comment: If you think "loops" are "special" I doubt you will find any of the easiest answers we can provide applicable.

Answer (score 2):

This is using regex, so import the regex library:

```
import re
```

Use the following Python to find individual digits:

```
a = re.findall('\d', string)
```

If you want more than one digit together use:

```
a = re.findall('\d+', string)
```

Then use the following to count (`len`) the `set` (which makes it unique):

```
len(set(a))
```

Comment: OK, as per new edit this answer is redundant but may be useful for others...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```py
len(set(a).intersection(map(str, range(10))))
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner without `re`, using plain `list` and `str` operations

```
x='a1s2d1d2d1d2d1'
>>> sum( i.isdigit() for i in list(set(list(x))) )
2
>>>
```

Breaking it down: convert `string` to `list` and then to `set` and then back to `list`, will remove duplicates and then count the digits.

```
>>>
>>> l = list(set(list(x)))
>>> sum( i.isdigit() for i in l )
2
```

Note: this **uses loop** inside one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you knew loop it would have been much much easier and would have looked pythonic. However, I have modified your code here and here is the solution using '**if-else**' statement and '**sets**'

```
s = set()
if "0" in num:
    s.add(0)
if "1" in num:
    s.add(1)
if "2" in num:
    s.add(2)
if "3" in num:
    s.add(3)
if "4" in num:
    s.add(4)
if "5" in num:
    s.add(5)
if "6" in num:
    s.add(6)
if "7" in num:
    s.add(7)
if "8" in num:
    s.add(8)
if "9" in num:
    s.add(9)
print(len(s))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is

```
count_dict = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i in num and i not in count_dict:
        count_dict[i] = 1 # just adding the integer to a dict
    else:
        continue


print('there are {} different integers in string {}'.format(len(count_dict), num)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
num=input()
count=0

for i in num:
    if i in '0123456789':
        count+=1

print(count)
```

You can use "in" in a single line